# C# CF 2.0 HttpRequest, no new connection

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I need to send a HttpRequest to a webserver with C# CF2.0.

At the momentan this is my code:

```
HTTPRequest.SendRequest("http://...",vars);
```

But the network is very legacy so the connection establishment fails often.

Is there a way with a permanent open connection?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running CF, I'm guessing you're on a mobile device, rather than embedded hardware. If that's the case then you have to code assuming the network is down.

What problem are you trying to solve that requires an always connected service? It might be that message queues give you a more robust mechanism.

Comment: The HttpRequest often fails because the network(wlan) doesnt response. Yes it is a Motorola Symbol MC70 PDA. With other programs it works (no sourcecode available) because the always think "connection is there".

Comment: Try looking at this, it may help you get around the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx

Comment: Sadly this is not what I need. Is there an advantage if I work with sockets?

Comment: I would imagine not, but it may be worth a try.